# Combination of Time/Data vectors into a text matrix in a specific order

Tags: bash, vector, awk

**Description of Intended Outcome:**

My input consists of several dozen folders with Names like these:

"FD=6944.88450 7244.2 4049.1 0.0250"

each folder contains a range of text files each containing a time and a data vector, like so:

```
0.0032771032 0.0000000
0.023277102 0.0000000
0.063277103 0.0000000
0.12327710 0.0000000
1.0032771 0.0000000
2.0032771 0.0000000
3.0032771 0.0000000
4.0032768 0.0000000
5.0032768 0.0000000
```

Where the left column is the time and the right the data vector. Each data file has a unique name (Note: unique in it's own folder they repeat in each folder). I need to iterate through the folder and read in the data vectors in a specified order depending on the name of the file. The intended output is something like this:

[Time-Vector] [Data-Vector-1] [Data-Vector-2] [Data-Vector-3] ...  [Data-Vector-20]

yielding a Matrix with 21 columns. The folder contains more files than the matrix will contain vectors, so some will be unused. Time-vectors or columns are identical for all files inside the folder.

**Description of what I tried:**

I tried for a mixture of bash and awk.

First I need to iterate through all the files in the folder, and find the file names, which I should be able to use for a standard string comparison, so I can read in the files in the required order.

To check this to this functions I introduced the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /the/correct/Directory/DataOutput

# Stringlist of Filenames
TIME='TIME.dat'
MeltMass='MeltMass.dat'
EjectedMass='EjectedMass.dat'

# Note: blank (=> contained in FILES) is by standard one of the field separators => end of file name assumed even with suppression operator "\"
Reassging new value to list of field separators IFS
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
# set me
FILES=./FD\=6944.88450\ 7244.2\ 4049.1\ 0.0250/*
for f in $FILES
do
  # echo "$f"
  filename=$(basename $f)
  echo $filename

  if [ "$filename"=="$TIME" ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $TIME
  elif [[ "$filename"=="$MeltMass" ]];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $MeltMass
  elif [ "$filename"=="$EjectedMass" ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $EjectedMass
  elif [ "$filename"=='DowncomerLevel.dat' ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo 'DowncomerLevel.dat'
  elif [ "$filename"=='MaxTemp_Core.dat' ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo 'MaxTemp_Core.dat'
  else 
    echo $filename

    echo 'Not found'
  fi

done
# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

echo $filename returns a list of the files in the directory. The if-then-else in the configuration does not work as expected. It gets stuck on the first entry (always returns):

```
    echo $filename
    echo $TIME
```

no matter what filename actually contains. I tried an alternative form using arrays:

```
files=( ./FD\=6944.88450\ 7244.2\ 4049.1\ 0.0250/*.dat)
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
  filename="${file##*/}"
#  filenameWithoutExtension="${filename%.*}"
  echo "$filenameWithoutExtension"

  if [ "$filename"=="$TIME" ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $TIME
  elif [[ "$filename"=="$MeltMass" ]];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $MeltMass
  elif [ "$filename"=="$EjectedMass" ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo $EjectedMass
  elif [ "$filename"=='DowncomerLevel.dat' ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo 'DowncomerLevel.dat'
  elif [ "$filename"=='MaxTemp_Core.dat' ];
  then
    echo $filename
    echo 'MaxTemp_Core.dat'
  else 
    echo $filename

    echo 'Not found'
   fi

done
```

but the same result. Anyone have any idea what's the reason for this problem and how to solve it?

Regards,

HobbsTuna

Comment: Spaces in filenames are the problem.  The only workaround is to be sure any constant filename string (no variables ) is surrounded by single quotes, and any filename variable is surround by double quotes. An example problem is: FILES=./FD\=6944.88450\ 7244.2\ 4049.1\ 0.0250/* -- you are globbing filenames the variable FILES will be filled with spaces, so all of your filenames are broken,.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. First of all I thought redifining the IFS would take care of the blanks. Secondly the Filenames who are actually compare don't contain any spaces (e.g. Time.dat, MeltMass.dat, MeltEject.dat etc.) and are correctly displayed by echo $filename. That is the part I use in my comparison, which is the part that isn't working, so I'm not sure I understand your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - find a list of files in a directory (`folders` are Windows terminology).

Try this:

```
find "FD=6944.88450 7244.2 4049.1 0.0250" -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r dirFile
do
    filename=$(basename "$dirFile")
    printf 'filename="%s"\n' "$filename"

    filenameWithoutExtension=$(basename "$dirFile" ".dat")
    printf 'filenameWithoutExtension="%s"\n' "$filenameWithoutExtension"
done
```

Did that work for you?

If so - what is it you want to do next? So far you've told us you need to process some, but not all files, and in some order, but AFAIK you haven't told us exactly which files or in what order or what the processing involves.

Base onyour comments below, I think you just have a list of specific files you want to process in a specific order, if they exist. The below should get you on the right track for that.

Here we want to process files a, b, and c in that order if they exist. a and c exist, b doesn't:

```
$ cat a
3 foo
7 bar
$
$ cat b
cat: b: No such file or directory
$
$ cat c
3 other
7 stuff
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("a b c",files)
    for (i=1; i in files; i++) {
        file = files[i]
        if ( (getline tmp < file) > 0) {
            # file exists and is not empty
            ARGV[ARGC++] = file
        }
        close(file)
    }
}

{
    time = $1
    data = $2

    if (!seen[time]++) {
        times[++numTimes] = time
    }

    time2data[time] = time2data[time] (NR==FNR ? "" : OFS) data
}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=numTimes; i++) {
        time = times[i]
        print time, time2data[time]
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk
3 foo other
7 bar stuff
```

Make sense?

Comment: It did work in the sense that it returns a list of all files, but the quoted code examples, can do that, too. I apologize for being unclear. The actual problem is that the list of files is done in an alphabetical order. Like this: `ADS_TimeDelay
AvgDebTempLP
CoreDebris_MCRP
Core_Debris_mSS
CoreDebris_SS
CoreDebris_SSOX
CoreDebris_UO2
CoreDebris_ZR
CoreDebris_ZrO2
DowncomerLevel
ECCS_MassFlow
EjectedMass
HydMassCont
Keff
LPDebris_MCRP
LPDebris_SS
LPDebris_SSOX
LPDebris_UO2
LPDebris_ZR
LPDebris_ZrO2
MaxTemp_Core
MaxTemp_LP
MeltMass
SS_Debris_LP
SSO2_Debris_LP
...



ZrO2_Debris_LP`

Comment: The order in the matrix has nothing to do with the alphabetical order, s I was trying to force the code to read from a specific input-file in the directory (e.g. "CoreDebris_UO2" first). So I'm trying to find "CoreDebris_UO2" per string comparison and if so read stuff from the file of the same name into a new input file, which will eventually turn into the matrix. Do you have an alternative method?

Comment: Are you saying you just have a list of specific file names and if they exist then you need to parse them in a specific order?

Comment: Yes? Note, that for the existing example the list of specific file names is the same for each folder, but that need not be the case for all examples. So, preferably I would like a method that works even when for a yet unknown file-list, assuming of course it contains the files necessary to make the matrix.

Comment: Check my updated answer. But what order do you want to process these unknown files in? if you don't know know what their names will be, how can you specify what order to process them in?

Comment: I will check your answer and probably come back with questions. Thanks for your time and effort either way. To answer your question: This is another misunderstanding. I know exactly which order the (subset of) files is supposed to appear in the matrix: It always starts with the time vector (available from every file) and would then progress to Data-1 (from EjectedMass) than Data-2 (from Keff) and so on for 20 data vectors.  What I DO NOT know apriori is the content of the folders and therefore the file list. This is software output with 100 of possible outputs.

Comment: The "necessary" files for the Matrix should always be present, we only have to pick them out of the (unknown) list in the correct order and combine them so that only the datavector (always) the second is added to the matrix, with the exception of the very first time, where we also want the time vector.

Comment: So does the solution I posted do what you want? Your problem is getting obscured by your use of domain-specific terminology. If what I posted doesn't do what you want, explain what you want simply in terms of files named things like a, b, c, etc. - talking about "Data-2 (from Keff)", etc. is not helpful, it just obfuscates the problem.

Comment: Ok. No at the moment it doesn't work. Sorry if I'm slow but I'm a bit of newbie at this and still trying to figure out what you are doing in the first place. I'm somewhat familiar with the cat command but to my knowledge "$" infers a link, you usage is 'strange'? What exactly is supposed to happen during the cat $ cat a
3 foo
7 bar stuff?

Comment: Holy crap. I'm sorry, I mean this in the nicest possible way but you need to read a shell intro at least before we go any further as I don't have time to explain such absolutely basic things. The book Bash Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson is good, otherwise google for an intro to shell or maybe post a new question somewhere asking what `$ cat file` means?